# How do you access the object that a PointerProperty points to?

Tags: python, interface, properties, panel

I have created a PointerProperty so that I can specify a target object that I want a my script to act on, but I can't seem to find any information about how to actually use the pointer property once I have it.

I have created the property in the `register()` function:

```
bpy.types.Scene.targetObject = PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)
```

And I'm drawing it successfully in my tool's control panel:

[image: tool panel]

But how do I actually operate on the selected object? ie:

```
# throws error "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'name'
print(bpy.types.Scene.targetObject.name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bpy.types.Scene` has a property `targetObject` that is a PointerProperty. That means *instances* of `bpy.types.Scene` have a property `targetObject` that is a `bpy.types.Object` (or None).

```
# This prints the targetObject for the current scene
print(bpy.context.scene.targetObject)
```

Comment: Got it, thanks!