# How to access pose bones via python in this condition?

Tags: python, armature

I'm making an add-on to boost my workflow. I want to add **custom shapes** to the bones of the *armature* selected in the `PointerProperty` from the panel. But according to my knowledge, I can only add **custom shapes** in the `posebones` of the *armature* which can be accessed by `bpy.context.object.pose.bones` but taking an *armature* like this I've already accessed `bpy.context.object.data`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

````
import bpy

class CUSTOM_PT_PANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Custom"
    bl_idname = "CUSTOM_PT_PANEL"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Custom"
     
    def draw (self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(context.scene, 'select_rig')
        layout.operator('add.custom_shape')
        
class CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Add custom shae"
    bl_idname = "add.custom_shape"
    
    def execute(self,context):
        armature = bpy.context.scene.select_rig
        
        #Custom Shape
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        shape = bpy.context.active_object
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
        shape.scale.y = 0.4
        shape.scale.z = 0.4
        bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='ONLY_FACE')
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
classes = [CUSTOM_PT_PANEL, CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR]

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Scene.select_rig = bpy.props.PointerProperty(name='Select Rig',type=bpy.types.Armature)
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake here is that you use `type=bpy.types.Armature` for the `PointerProperty`. This allows the user to pick an *Armature* which sounds right. But this data block has no pose bones. The *Object* of type 'ARMATURE' has actually the pose data. You can see this in the outliner.

`type=bpy.types.Armature`:
[image: aramature selection]

What you really want is the *Mannequin* object (`type=bpy.types.Object`):
[image: objects]

Now the user can pick one of all objects. Of course, you don't want that the *Camera* can be picked which makes no sense. To limit the selection to *Objects* of type *ARMATURE* you can use a poll function and check the type of the object in question. This works like a filter:
[image: pick an armature object]

Here's the modified script. The validation check (lines 22 to 25) is just for testing and never should fail when the filter is correct.

```py
import bpy

class CUSTOM_PT_PANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Custom"
    bl_idname = "CUSTOM_PT_PANEL"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Custom"
     
    def draw (self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(context.scene, 'select_rig')
        layout.operator('add.custom_shape')
        
class CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Add custom shae"
    bl_idname = "add.custom_shape"
    
    def execute(self,context):
        armature = bpy.context.scene.select_rig
        
        # this validation check should never fail because scene_mychosenobject_poll() 
        # will limit the selection
        if armature.type != 'ARMATURE':
            raise ValueError(f'Select an armature not {armature.type}')
        
        #Custom Shape
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        shape = bpy.context.active_object
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
        shape.scale.y = 0.4
        shape.scale.z = 0.4
        bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='ONLY_FACE')
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
        
        # assign the custom shape to a bone 
        armature.pose.bones['LowerLeg.L'].custom_shape = shape   # <== adjust the bone name!
        
        return {'FINISHED'}


# filter the selection
def scene_mychosenobject_poll(self, object):
    return object.type == 'ARMATURE'

  
classes = [CUSTOM_PT_PANEL, CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR]

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

    # select_rig should point to an Object of type 'ARMATURE'
    bpy.types.Scene.select_rig = bpy.props.PointerProperty(name='Select Rig',
        type=bpy.types.Object, poll=scene_mychosenobject_poll)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Related questions:

- [Limit "prop_search" to Specific Types of Objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/75185/107598)
- [How do you access the object that a PointerProperty points to?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/218322/107598)

Comment: Thank you very much.